# What performs better string::+= or sstream::<<

Tags: c++

In context of c++ stl library what performs better string::+= or sstream::<< or it depends upon something else?

EDIT:
Does it depend on the size of data we are appending?

Comment: Do you realize they're not equivalent?

Comment: @jrok, true - but appending to a string stream and concatenating a string are attempting to achieve the same thing (produce a string from other items), and therefore are comparable in this context.

Comment: I mean append on string work fast or on sstream?

Comment: Both of them should run in O(n) time in total if n characters were appended. The constant factor can be different and implementation-dependent though. Measure it for yourself.

Comment: @pts they're amortized to O(n) but could in theory have significant hits for reallocating the underlying memory and copying the array. @Sharmila if you have an idea of how large your string will be, you can potentially drastically cut down on the allocation overhead by using `string::reserve` before going into whatever is doing the +=. For a one time thing, I'd probably use `+=`, but in a loop I'd try to do something smarter.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT:
It is recommend to use string::+= in general and sstream::<< when you know your append strings are huge.

Comment: Do you have any quote or link about implementation of `sstream` which says it implemented like linked-list?

Comment: Since when is `ostringstream` implemented as a linked list.  I've never seen  this, and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why would `stringstream` be faster than plain concatenation for big strings?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on many various parameters, the main parameter is the implementation of these operators and compiler itself.

Just a simple test in a specific version of a compiler can be a naive observation. For example simply adding a short string 10,000,000 times to a `string` or `istringstream` and measuring the time is done [here](http://ideone.com/4od3pE). It shows `+=` is faster that `<<`.

```
time (ms):534.02   // For +=
time (ms):927.578  // For <<
```

In your real application, you should use `+=`, if you suspect it's slow and damaging your performance then test another one. Profiling is the keyword.

Comment: You'd have to compare `sstream::write`, though, because that's what does naked string concatenation.

Comment: does it depend on the size of data we are appending?

Comment: For which implementation?  (I would expect this generally to be the case, but it's easy to imagine implementations where it wasn't, and even implementations where the the opposite held.)

Comment: Also, of course, for what sort of string lengths, and what sort of inserted data?  This too could cause a change in performance.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Of course you're right. The real benchmark should be done by himself in his application. I've updated the answer to mention it -- _I always like your great hints_

Answer (score 0):

In addition for string+= recommendation I would add that if you append plain char* and know the length of it you should use string.append(data*, length) method which will save you internal length calculation.
Example for mixed C/C++ code
instead of

```
  char temp[256];
  sprintf(temp, <some insane pattern>, <some valuable data>,...);
  str += temp;
```

you should use

```
  char temp[256];
  const int length = sprintf(temp, <some insane pattern>, <some valuable data>,...);
  str.apeend(temp, length);
```